# ASP.NET MVC User Interface

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have problem of checkbox UI. It's not proper when I used it with `@Html.EditorFor`.... It appears properly in html only, meaning the  html control is showing properly in the UI but when I use css classes with `@Html.EditorFor` the UI is not shown properly.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Create" }))
{
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Member_Temple, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Member_Temple, new { @class = "checkbox form-control" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="agree" class="control-label col-md-2">Temple</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-9">
      <input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px" class="checkbox form-control" id="agree" name="agree" />
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Model

```
[DisplayName("Temple")]
public bool Member_Temple { get; set; }
```

> View Page Source

Problem is `style="width: 20px"` which is added in the html source but not with `@Html...`

Code with `@Html.EditorFor` or `@Html.CheckboxFor`

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Temple field is required." htmlattributes="{ class = checkbox form-control }" id="Member_Temple" name="Member_Temple" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Code with html only

```
<input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px" class="checkbox form-control" id="tmp" name="tmp">
```

Comment: Why not use `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? (for less that 5.1, you cannot pass html attributes, for 5.1+ the syntax is `@Html.EditorFor(m=> m, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })`)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried @html.CheckBoxFor but didn't work.

Comment: `but didn't work` is our favorite explanation.

Comment: If `@html.CheckBoxFor()` did not work, then you did not use it correctly. Show what you tried.

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Member_Temple, new { @class = "checkbox form-control" })

Comment: @JigneshGadhia, That works perfectly. What is the problem?

Comment: You have to explain EXACTLY what "does not work" means, and EXACTLY what your expected result is, and what results you are actually getting that are different from those results.  We simply cannot help you with vague comments like "doesn't work".

Comment: Got the solution need to add style="width: 20px". Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [CheckBoxFor Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)? In your usage, it would look like:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Member_Temple, new { @class = "checkbox form-control" })
```